# How to call the data object from another namespace in already namespaced kedro pipeline?

Tags: namespaces, kedro

I have the following namespaced pipelines in kedro:

```
def create_pipeline(**kwargs) -> Pipeline:
    pipeline_instance = pipeline(
        [
            node(
                func=split_data,
                inputs=["model_input_table", "params:model_options"],
                outputs=["X_train", "X_test", "y_train", "y_test"],
                name="split_data_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=train_model,
                inputs=["X_train", "y_train"],
                outputs="regressor",
                name="train_model_node",
            ),
            node(
                func=evaluate_model,
                inputs=["regressor", "X_test", "y_test"],
                outputs=None,
                name="evaluate_model_node",
            ),
        ]
    )
    ds_pipeline_1 = pipeline(
        pipe=pipeline_instance,
        inputs={"model_input_table":"feature_engineering.ds1_input"}
        namespace="active_modelling_pipeline",
    )
    ds_pipeline_2 = pipeline(
        pipe=pipeline_instance,
        inputs={"model_input_table":"feature_engineering.ds2_input"}
        namespace="candidate_modelling_pipeline",
        parameters={"params:model_options": "params:model_options_experimental"},
    )

    return pipeline(
      pipe = ds_pipeline_1 + ds_pipeline_2, 
      namespace="modeling_pipeline"
```

I want the "model_input_table" be different for ds_pipeline_1 and ds_pipeline_2, and come from another namespace, e.g. "feature_engineering.ds1_input" (this is how it is stored in catalog.yml).

The same for params: I want to map them to "params:feature_engineering.model_options_experimental"

Namespacing this pipeline as "modeling_pipeline" enforces:

- "feature_engineering.ds1_input" to "modeling_pipeline.feature_engineering.ds1_input"
- "params:feature_engineering.model_options_experimental" to ""params:modeling_pipeline.feature_engineering.model_options_experimental"

These data objects do not exist in my Data Catalog.

How to solve this problem? What would be the workaround?